# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que Pywhatkit me escriba los caracteres con acento?

Tags: python, pywhatkit

Por ejemplo, al enviar el siguiente mensaje:

```
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg_to_group(
"#################", 
"¡hola! A continuación te comparto la noticia más importante del día: \n - ", 
hour, min, 20, True, 3)
```

el resultado que me arroja es este:

```
hola! A continuacin te comparto la noticia ms importante del da:
-
```

edición:

Al usar .encode('utf-8') con una sola linea de caracteres soluciona el problema, ahora digamos que quiero concatenar algunos títulos y enlaces de un dataframe así:

```
mensaje = ("¡hola! A continuación te comparto la noticia más importante del día: \n - " + titulos[1] + "\nConsulta más en:" + links[1]).encode('UTF-8')
```

En este caso dice "int" is not iterable, cuando no tengo for loops, o datos int, tampoco envía un mensaje en Wpp. Y si convierto todo en str de la siguiente manera:

```
mensaje = str(("¡hola! A continuación te comparto la noticia más importante del día: \n - " + titulos[1] + "\nConsulta más en:" + links[1]).encode('UTF-8'))
```

me arroja el mensaje, pero con carácter así: *\xe2\x80\x93* Por ejemplo, \xe2hola... etc (estos caracteres no son el resultado, son solo brindar mejor claridad)

Comment: Estuve revisando el código fuente de pywhatkit y parece que utiliza pyautogui para escribir el mensaje cuando el número de telefono no tiene + ni _. pyautogui no se lleva bien con las tildes y no las escribe. Puede que el verdadero problema esté en que el id del grupo no cumpliera las condiciones antes mencionadas.

Comment: Sobre tu edición, simplemente concatena todas las cadenas que quieras, encierras la suma entre parentesis y LUEGO haces el encode("utf-8"). Ejemplo: ("hola"+"mundo").encode("utf-8")

Comment: Hola @DanteS. Te agradezco por estar pendiente del hilo. Esto que mencionas es algo que he hecho, pero al final no me envía el mensaje y dice "int" is not iterable, cuando no tengo for loops, o datos int. Haré nuevamente una edición para dar más claridad, nuevamente, gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que enviar el mensaje en UTF-8, como `"del día".encode("UTF-8")`:

```
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg(
"+56941441464",
"¡hola! A continuación te comparto la noticia más importante del día: \n - ".encode("UTF-8"),
8, 39, 20, True, 3)
```

produce:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvió!!